# Wordpress Add New User - Send an Activation Email

Tags: email, profiles, email-verification

I edited the Add New User Profile page to add some custom fields (I'm not using multisite). My question is if there is a way to send out an activation/confirmation email to new users once I manually add them in?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by adding this code to save_extra_profile_fields() in add_action ( 'user_register', 'save_extra_profile_fields');

```
$hash = md5( $random_number );
add_user_meta( $user_id, 'hash', $hash );

$user_info = get_userdata($user_id);
$to = $user_info->user_email;           

$subject = 'Member Verification'; 
$message = 'Hello,';
$message .= "\n\n";
$message .= 'Welcome...';
$message .= "\n\n";
$message .= 'Username: '.$un;
$message .= "\n";
$message .= 'Password: '.$pw;
$message .= "\n\n";
$message .= 'Please click this link to activate your account:';
$message .= home_url('/').'activate?id='.$un.'&key='.$hash;
$headers = 'From: noreply@test.com' . "\r\n";           
wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you add a new user via the backend a confirmation email is sent automatically, unless you check the skip checkbox. The new user shouldn't appear in the UI until confirmed

Comment: When adding a user via the backend, the only option I have is "Send this password to the new user by email". However, it doesn't seem to work. Could it be because I'm using add_user_meta on the user_register action?

Comment: user meta etc should have no impact. I advise you test with a gmail account and the + feature to simulate multiple accounts